# Start/kill pulseaudio with toggle button

Tags: pulseaudio, button

I would like to have a desktop toggle button, if pressed: 'red' or 'on', if released: 'green' or 'off' to actuate 'pulseaudio --start' and 'pulseaudio --kill'. That would allow me to control pulseaudio without the terminal command line.

It is probably simple but I could not follow gtk's instructions.

Thanks

Comment: A desktop toggle button means an icon on the desktop that you simply double click to toggle start/kill, right?

Answer (score 1):

### How to toggle pulseaudio on/off

**1.** **Disable Pulseaudio from automatically restarting when killed**

Add `autospawn = no` to `~/.pulse/client.conf`, if such file/folder doesn't exist, create it yourself via GUI or do it all at once:

`mkdir ~/.pulse && echo 'autospawn = no' > ~/.pulse/client.conf`

**2.** **Create a script to toggle pulseaudio status**

Open a text editor (e.g. gedit), copy/paste the following, and save it somewhere under your `$HOME`.

```
#!/bin/bash

PULSE_STATUS=$(pulseaudio -v --check 2>&1)

if [[ $PULSE_STATUS == *"PID"* ]]; then

   pulseaudio --kill

else
   pulseaudio --start
fi
```

**3.** **Create a .desktop to run the script**

Open a text editor (e.g. gedit), copy/paste the following, and save it as `Toggle-Pulseaudio.desktop` somewhere under your `$HOME` (e.g. `~/Desktop`, if you want to double click it to toggle pulseaudio).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Toggle-Pulseaudio
Comment=Toggle Pulseaudio on and off
Exec=/path/to/script
Icon=/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/256x256/status/audio-volume-medium.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Once saved, right click on it and go to *Properties > Permissions* and tick *Allow executing file as  a program*. If you want to have in on your Launcher/Dash, simply drag with your mouse the .desktop the the Launcher.

---

Now you can toggle pulseaudio on and off from your desktop and from Dash.